# Ionic 5: Remove White Space between Collapsable Header and Ion Content while Swipe down

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I am using collapsable header in my ionic 5 app. I am getting this white space between my ion-header and ion-content when I swipe down on my page.

[image]

My code looks like below:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="false" no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Requests
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button class="person-icon" (click)="showProfile()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="person-outline" mode="md" color="light"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons> 
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense" no-border>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title size="large">Requests</ion-title>   
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-searchbar class="ion-text-left"  style="padding-bottom:0px;" mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="searchReq" animated type="search" placeholder="Search"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-header>
....
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong or how I can remove that white space or lock my collapsable header with main header?